# Non-rectangular 'clickable' area

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a 3D map with many different shaped buildings.  I would like users to click a building on the map, which would act as a segue to a new view.

I planned to go about this by creating invisible buttons the same shapes as the buildings, and then laying them on top of the imageview (which holds the map).

After doing some reading I found that it isn't as simple as I thought to create custom buttons (I think that I will have to do a lot of sublcassing and customization, which doesn't seem reasonable when I have 50+ different shaped buttons to make), so I was wondering if there was another aproach I could use to solve this problem.

---

Edit:  I should add that right now that all functionality is working, but I am having to use default rectangular buttons, with alpha set to 0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED TO IMPROVE DATAMODEL**

To do this you will have a UIView with your map image in the background. You can do this with either a UIImageView or by rendering the image yourself in drawRect.

You will then define several CGPath references. One for each building by doing something like this... [How to create CGPathRef from Array of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309930/how-to-create-cgpathref-from-array-of-points) The points will be the corners of each building.

Now store these paths in an array somehow. You will need one path for every "clickable" 
building.

I would store the paths inside a Building object or something...

```
@interface Building : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGPath path;

@end
```

Now in the UIView subclass you override `- (void)touchesBegan...`. You can then get the touch point and iterate through your paths to find which one is touched...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    for (Building *building in self.buildings) {
        if (CGPathContainsPoint(building.path, CGAffineTransformIdentity, touchPoint, YES)) {
            //the touch was inside this building!
            //now do something with this knowledge.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying put my current UIImageView inside of a UIView, and then just check the location of all touches ?

Answer (score 1):

I had once to implement a meteo application.
We did a map - with several clickable regions.
The easiest way to define those non-rectangular areas is to define them as `UIBezierPath`, and use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`
UIBezierPath uses a CGPath, but it's pure Objective-C.
Other advantage on CGPath, you can easily fill / stroke these paths - using random color - which can be neat for seeing them when debugging

So

```
//in you .h, or in class extension

//an array of UIBezierPath you create
// each bezierPath represent an area.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myShapes;

//in your .m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //load stuff
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.view addGesture:tap];

    // ...
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    UIBezierPath *recognizedArea = nil;
    //if your shapes are defined in self.view coordinates : 
    CGPoint hitPoint = [tap locationInView:self.view];
    for(UIBezierPath *regionPath in self.myShapes){
        if([regionPath containsPoint:tap]){
            recognizedArea = regionPath;
            break;
        }
    }
    //handle touch for THIS specific area when recognizedArea isn't nil
    if(recognizedArea){
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    }
    // you might also iterate with a normal integer increment
    // and use the path index to retrieve region-specific-data from another array

}
```