# Change the Color of CGPOINT

Tags: sprite-kit, cgpoint, skspritenode

i have managed to create a SKspritenode , Make it move around , although i want to change the color of every CGPOINT that the node Passes by .

Anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CGShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKShapeNode/path) to draw a path which consists of CGPoints your node passed throught.

For direction on creating a path from points check out [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309930/how-to-create-cgpathref-from-array-of-points)